# Window.open() Width + Height Resize Doesn't Work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, window, height, width

I am working on a google extension that opens four random pop-ups every hour (and opens different pop-ups during the day and night).

The pop-up sizes vary so I set each size of the pop-up url but it does not seem to work as seen in the picture. Does anyone have any ideas why it is not working?

Thank you so much :')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYWTV.jpg)

```
function showPopup() {


    let date = new Date();
    let h = date.getHours();

    if(h > 5 && h < 20)
    {

        var Popups = [


            {
                url: 'https://looking4love.glitch.me/', // Day time -- Gorse
                width: 400,
                height: 530,
        
            },

            {
                url: 'https://meetme2day.glitch.me/',  //Canada goose 
                width: 400,
                height: 530,
     
            },

            {
                url: 'https://chat2me.glitch.me/', // Cow Parsley
                width: 400,
                height: 530,
     
            },

            {
                url: 'https://meet-me-2nite.glitch.me/', //Eurasian Coot
                width: 530,
                height: 400,

            },

            {
                url: 'https://meetmenow.glitch.me/', // Hawthorn
                width: 400,
                height: 530,
 
            },

            {
                url: 'https://looking4relatioship.glitch.me/', // Bluebell
                width: 400,
                height: 530,
        
            },

            {
                url: 'https://availablenow.glitch.me/', //Moss  
                width: 400,
                height: 530,
      
            },

            {
                url: 'https://cute-single-needs-lov.glitch.me/', // Poppies
                width: 530,
                height: 400,
      
            },
        ];

        var a = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];
        var b = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];
        var c = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];
        var d = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];

        console.log(a,b,c,d);

        // daytime
        window.open(a.url, 'Go Outside!', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=20,left=20,width=${a.width},height=${a.height}`);

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(b.url, 'Go Outside! 02', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=200,left=200,width=${b.width},height=${b.height}`);
        }, 1000);
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(c.url, 'Go Outside! 03', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=50,left=620,width=${c.width},height=${c.height}`);
        }, 2000);
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(d.url, 'Go Outside! 04', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=100,left=820,width=${d.width},height=${d.height}`);
        }, 3000);
    }
    else
    {
        var Popups = [
            {
                url: 'https://feeling-lonely.glitch.me/', // Night time  -- Robin
                width: 400,
                height: 529,
        
            },

            {
                url: 'https://talk-2-me.glitch.me/',  // Mallard
                width: 400,
                height: 529,
     
            },

            {
                url: 'https://looking4relatioship.glitch.me', // Blue bell
                width: 400,
                height: 529,
     
            },

            {
                url: 'https://chat2metonite.glitch.me/', //Fuchisas
                width: 400,
                height: 529,

            },

            {
                url: 'https://freetonight.glitch.me/', //Viviparous
                width: 400,
                height: 529,

            },

            {
                url: 'https://chat-tonight.glitch.me/', //Teasel
                width: 400,
                height: 529,

            },

            {
                url: 'https://free-tonight.glitch.me/', //Six-spot
                width: 529,
                height: 400,

            },
        ];

        var a = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];
        var b = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];
        var c = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];
        var d = Popups.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Popups.length - 1), 1)[0];

        // nighttime
        window.open(a.url + "?test=abc", 'Go Outside!', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=20,left=20,width=${a.width},height=${a.height}`);

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(b.url + "?test=abc", 'Go Outside! 02', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=200,left=200,width=${b.width},height=${b.height}`);
        }, 1000);
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(c.url + "?test=abc", 'Go Outside! 03', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=50,left=620,width=${c.width},height=${c.height}`);
        }, 2000);
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(d.url + "?test=abc", 'Go Outside! 04', `directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=100,left=820,width=${d.width},height=${d.height}`);
        }, 3000);
    }


    
    let paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    for (elt of paragraphs) {
        elt.style['background-color']= '#000000';
        elt.style['color']= '#000000';
        // elt.style['filter'] = 'blur(50px)';
        // elt.innerText = "";
    }
}

setInterval(() => {
    let d = new Date();
    let m = d.getMinutes();
    let s = d.getSeconds();

    if(s % 20 == 0) // this for testing              
    // if(m == 21 && s == 0) // this for once an hour    
    {
        // it is zero minutes and zero seconds...
        showPopup();
    }
}, 500);
```